# Unexpected Token } on line that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, steam, steambot

Says that there is an unexpected token } at a line that doesnt exist. I have tried makeing sure that every bracket has a partner and so on, and I cant seem tio figure it out. It's probably a dumb mistake since its late. Any help is appreciated.

Error code:

```js
    SyntaxError: /bots/crypto/data/config.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1328
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
        at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:671:27)
        at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/bots/crypto/app.js:1:78)
        at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

I tried to make sure they all had pairs, with no luck

```
    {
        "address": "redacted",
        "mnemonic": "redacted",
        "accountIndex": 1,
        "admins": "76561198850513237",
        "username": "redacted",
        "password": "redacted",
        "shared_secret": "redacted=",
        "identity_secret": "redacted=",
        "minimumConfirmations": 2,
        "network": "test",
        "satoshisPerByte": 2,
        "website": "redacted",
        "discord": "none",
        "group": "redacted",
        "owner": "redacted",
        "csgoKeys": [
            "eSports Key",
            "Shadow Case Key",
            "Huntsman Case Key",
            "Chroma Case Key",
            "Horizon Case Key",
            "Gamma Case Key",
            "Clutch Case Key",
            "Glove Case Key",
            "Prisma Case Key",
            "Operation Vanguard Case Key",
            "Operation Wildfire Case Key",
            "Danger Zone Case Key",
            "Operation Breakout Case Key",
            "Operation Phoenix Case Key",
            "Gamma 2 Case Key",
            "Chroma 2 Case Key",
            "Spectrum 2 Case Key",
            "Winter Offensive Case Key",
            "Chroma Case Key",
            "Chroma 3 Case Key",
            "Spectrum Case Key",
            "Falchion Case Key"
        ],
        "tfKeys": [
            "Mann Co. Supply Crate Key"
        ],
        "price": {
            "csgo": 1.63,
            "tf": 1.60,
            "hydra": 1
        },
        "sellprice": {
            "csgo": 1.53,
            "tf": 1.52,
            "hydra": 0.5
        },
        "enabled": {
            "tf": 1,
        },
        "enableSell": 1
    }
```

removed any personal info like TOTP auth generator keys and such.
I want this to work.

Comment: the object you posted is valid - the problem exists elsewhere - oh, it's JSON ...

Comment: Closing inverted comma is missing on "website": "redacted, this line . Replace it with  "website": "redacted",

Comment: @Abhishek - that was probably a typo when redacting before OP posted here - you'll see the edited version of the object is valid

Comment: yea, i messed up and I edited the " back. it was an issue when making it say redacted. @JaromandaX is right

Comment: a useful tool is https://jsonlint.com/ for validating JSON :p

Comment: use a json viewer such as this (https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) to validate your json object -> issue found at line 55 -> remove the comma after "tf": 1

Answer (score 3):

Remove `,` in the following line

```
"enabled": {
        "tf": 1
    },
```

Comment: realized what you meant, worked like a charm. Thanks a ton man. :)

Comment: @Impulse Glad to help you.. Please accept the answer if it really helped..